# Как сделать вывод просроченных записей, записей на завтра и на неделю вперед

Tags: php, mysql

Писал скрипт, но он не работает так как нужно.

Суть в том, что при добавлении комментария, клиенту в базу заносится 2 даты:

**client_dateA** - дата последнего контакта;

**client_dateB** - дата следующего контакта;

В системе есть вывод клиентов по дате, но он работает как-то странно, мне нужно, чтобы выводило количество записей **COUNT(client_id)**, для которых дата следующего контакта будет меньше, чем текущая дата дня (это считается просроченной записью, если менеджер её не прокомментировал за целый день и на следующий день она становится просрочкой) также нужно вывести количество клиентов, у которых дата следующего контакта назначена на завтра и на неделю.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как грамотно это сделать.

Код, который делает запрос сейчас

```
<?php   

// Подключение скриптов ядра
include 'engine/function_mysqlServer.php';
include 'engine/function_configServer.php';
// Подключение скриптов ядра

// Проверка авторизации пользователя
if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) and isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) 
{    
    $userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_id = '".intval($_COOKIE['id'])."' LIMIT 1"));
    $username = $userdata['users_login'];
}
// Проверка авторизации пользователя

// Вывод 40 записей о клиентах на сегодня
$main = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB = '".$date."' LIMIT 40");

if ($date == $row['client_dateB']) 
{
    while ($row_arr = mysql_fetch_array($main)) 
    {
            echo "<div class=\"content_min\">";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:left;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_company']." (ID: ".$row_arr['client_number'].")</p>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:right;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_name']."</p><br>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:left;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_dateA']."</p>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:right;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_phone']."</p><br><br>";
            echo "<p style=\"line-height:20px;color:#676666;\">".$row_arr['client_comment']."</p></div>";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "<div class=\"mess_coffe\">".$username.", на сегодня у Вас отсутствуют записи</div>";
}

    // Общее количество зарегистрированных клиентов менеджером
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."'");
    $res_sql = mysql_fetch_row( $sql );
    // Общее количество зарегистрированных клиентов менеджером

    // Просроченные записи на текущий день
    $overdue = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB < NOW()");
    $overdue_result = mysql_fetch_row( $overdue );
    // Просроченные записи на текущий день

    // Зарегистрированные клиенты на завтра
    $tomorrow = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB > '".$date."'");
    $tomorrow_result = mysql_fetch_row( $tomorrow );
    // Зарегистрированные клиенты на завтра
```

Comment: client_dateB если тип DATE то < current_date(), если TIMESTAMP то < current_timestamp(). http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

для получения всех записей из таблицы запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select * from table
```

для того что бы получить список записей на завтра, необходимо в исходный запрос передать параметр типа дата время и по нему отфильтровать исходную таблицу, т.е. в Вашем случае sql запрос мог бы выглядеть как то так:

```
select * from table where client_dateB = @date
```

меняя условия сравнения в конструкции `client_dateB = @date` Вы сможете получить данные за вчера если измените знак `=` на знак `<`

для получения же записей за период в запрос необходимо передать два параметра: дату начала и дату окончания и указать что интересуют записи между двумя этими датами, это можно сделать например так:

```
select * from table where client_dateB >= @dateStart and client_dateB <=@dateStop
```

или же использовать оператор `Between`, тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select * from table where client_dateB between @dateStart and @dateStop
```

Comment: у меня в базе данных все даты записей стоят в типе данных varchar (тупость) я знаю, но понятия не имею как преобразовать их в   current_date() или что там нужно для нормальной работы с датами

Comment: @CyberX строка в iso формате? есть ли доступ к бд на уровне изменения таблицы?

Comment: Как тип данных в phpmyadmin DATE
преобразовать на тот вид который мне нужен? а то он лупит в таком формате (2016-06-24), а мне нужно (24.06.2016)

Comment: Как мне убрать эту проблему с типами данных, чтобы даты были такими какими они должны были быть и чтобы была возможностях работы с ними (по примеру выше перечисленных вопросов)

Comment: если есть возможность изменить структуру таблицы, то я бы добавил колонки для хранения времени в `DateTime`, заполнил их на основании текстовых значений. а `DateTime` значение уже можно будет легко привести к необходимому Вам формату

Comment: Могу дать доступ в phpmyadmin на время проведения технических работ, если поможешь с этой бедой, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

так попробуй

```
$today  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$overdue = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`client_dateB`) < $today");
```